# Contradictive google content experiment results

Tags: google-analytics, usability, ab-testing, google-experiments

We are using Google Experiments heavily through the experiments api and recently started seeing experiments ending with the winner having lower score than other variations -- see the attached screenshots of two recent experiments.

Anyone else seen that? Do you have any idea what does this mean?

[image: Analytics contradictory experiment 1]

[image: Analytics contradictory experiment 2]

Answer (score 0):

Probably because confidence it's really low, so Google it's not confident to apply any variation.

> 4. Choosing the winner of your experiment
>
> Over time, you should see either the original ad setting or the
>   variation outperform the other. To help you decide the right time to
>   choose your winner, we calculate a confidence score for the two
>   settings. This score indicates how likely the original or the
>   variation is to be the better performing (e.g., the highest earning)
>   setting.
>
> We recommend that you wait until one of the scores reaches at least
>   95% before you choose that setting as the winner. When a setting has a
>   95% confidence score it means that we are 95% certain that that
>   setting is the better performing of the two.

You can read more:

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6321879?hl=en

I suggest also this page:
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6321909

> When you're choosing the winner of your experiment, we encourage you
>   to consider the Overall Change as well as the revenue (RPM) and the
>   relative Quality Score. The Overall Change equals the change in RPM
>   plus the change in Quality Score of the variation. In general, a
>   positive Overall Change will result in better long-term performance,
>   even when either the RPM change or the Quality Score change is
>   negative. In situations where the RPM and the Quality Score point to
>   different winners, a positive Overall Change can help you to make a
>   final decision.

Comment: I am not sure you are right. On those specific tests, there are 100K sessions on each variation, with +9% change on the KPI. That should generate quite of a confidence on the winner. More over, if significance was not reached, why did the test stop prematurely? Also note those are google analytic tests and not Adsense tests.